# I'm trying to figure out how to add to a list of dictionaries, rather than create a list of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function, GetFunds, that returns a dictionary. It looks like this:

> [    {    "currency": "BTC",    "available": 0.460594115839,
>   "reserved": 0.0    } ]

to me this looks like a list with one dictionary in it. I would like to put more dictionaries in the list. So I try this code:

```
funds=GetFunds(1, "BTC")
funds=funds+(GetFunds(2, "BTC"))
funds=funds + GetFunds(1, "DIVI")
funds=funds + GetFunds(2, "DIVI")
print(funds)
```

and the result is a list of lists (I think)

> [   {
>       "currency": "BTC",
>       "available": 0.460594115839,
>       "reserved": 0.0   } ] [   {
>       "currency": "BTC",
>       "available": 0.460594115839,
>       "reserved": 0.0   } ][   {
>       "currency": "BTC",
>       "available": 2.002708880342,
>       "reserved": 0.449841884826   } ][   {
>       "currency": "DIVI",
>       "available": 6966346.17416024,
>       "reserved": 0.0   } ][   {
>       "currency": "DIVI",
>       "available": 6285691.0243108,
>       "reserved": 795457.15508981   } ]

But I think I want a single list with 4 elements, each of which is a dictionary....a single set of square braces

I have tried simply using '+', I have tried .append, btu I guess thats just for strings

Shown above

I want a single list of multiple dictionaries.

Comment: Lists in python have a method called `append` that allows to do exactly what you want. So instead using the `+` use `funds.append(GetFunds(...))`

Comment: @dcg `+` is the same as that tho, so by all means the `funds` are all strings

Comment: @U9-Forward So `funds=funds+[d for d in GetFunds(2, "BTC")]` should solve it, right?

Comment: @dcg No.. that will be a list with one string element, that's gonna be even worse :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there strings, so use `json.loads`:

```
import json
funds=json.loads(GetFunds(1, "BTC"))
funds=funds + json.loads(GetFunds(2, "BTC"))
funds=funds + json.loads(GetFunds(1, "DIVI"))
funds=funds + json.loads(GetFunds(2, "DIVI"))
print(funds)
```

Or little less recommended, using `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
funds=ast.literal_eval(GetFunds(1, "BTC"))
funds=funds + ast.literal_eval(GetFunds(2, "BTC"))
funds=funds + ast.literal_eval(GetFunds(1, "DIVI"))
funds=funds + ast.literal_eval(GetFunds(2, "DIVI"))
print(funds)
```

Comment: OK, this worked great.

However, I don't understand why "it's because there are strings" as the problem was so obvious to you. The strings are in dictionaries (right?) and I just wanted to make a list of dictionaries. Why does the presence of a string as a key matter?

Comment: @Shandor I see from your output, it is dictionaries inside strings, so that needed to be corrected, also don't forget, accept it if it works

Comment: so I just checked the type. 

<class 'str'>

So the entire "list with one dictionary in it" is just a string? How did you know it was a string?

Just saw your comment. So...thanks. will move on.

Comment: Sorry! New to this!

Answer (score 0):

If the result is a list it should work:

```
a = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
b = {'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}
aa = [a]
aa.extend([b])
aa
```

result:

```
 [{'b': 2, 'a': 1}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}]
```

So:

```
funds=GetFunds(1, "BTC")
funds.extend((GetFunds(2, "BTC")))
```

should work.

Otherwise check if it is effectively a list (as it seems to be).

```
type(aa)
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Something is wrong. I think U-9 Forward got the answer "there are strings" that is messing something up. When I tried this way, I got:

    funds.append((GetFunds(2, "BTC")))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: So it is not a list. In this case you should use json / ast.literal_eval as U-9 Forward suggested. Or make you original function return it as a dictionary/list that would be probably even better.

Comment: Exactly what I did. Thanks. I'm still baffled as to how he knew it was a single string and not a list with a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, so I'm posting an answer instead.

It's obvious that GetFunds returns a string by looking at the second snippet you posted. You're right, when you're looking at something that looks like [{key: value}] my first impulse would also be "this is a list with one dictionary". However, in your second snippet you have something like [{key: value}][{key: value}]. This is obviously not a list of dictionaries or a list of lists of dictionaries. A list of dictionaries would look like [{k: v}, {k: v}], and a list of lists of dictionaries would look like [[{k: v}], [{k: v}]]. That tells me that when you thought you were appending elements to a list, you were actually concatenating two strings (which happened to have characters in them that made it look like it was a list, most likely to be used with JSON). Notice how the open and closing square brackets are back to back.

Comment: Thank you. but yeah, not obvious to newcomer like me. I correlate strings with "", but I realize they alse are just arrays of characters.... sooo... now it makes sense